# XML into Mysql one element in wrong row

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I read and show the content of an XML and everything is fine. Than i put the data from the XML into a database. The problem is that all rows are correct except the  one with the element 'bericht'. The text from 'bericht' doesn't match to the rest from the row anymore. With other words,  e.g. the 'bericht' from row 5 is in the database written in row 9 and the 'bericht' from row 9 is in row 17 or where ever. the other elements are still where they should be.
The XML is encoded with UTF-8 without BOM. In some text of 'bericht' are a couple aof wordwraps and i guess also some other chars that would mess up the data in mysql?

With this code i read the XML into a table:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post" />
    <table id="Wagen">
        <thead>
          <tr>        
            <th>Typ</th>
            <th>Kennzeichen</th>
            <th>Bericht</th>
             <th>Fahrer</th>
           </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>

    <?php
       $url = ('./cars.xml');
       $xml = simplexml_load_file( urlencode($url), null, true);


        foreach ( $xml->car as $cars ) :?>
    <tr>        
            <td><input type="hidden" name="name[]" value="<?php echo  $cars->typ; ?>"><?php echo $cars->typ; ?></td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="kfz-nr[]" value="<?php echo $cars->plate; ?>"><?php echo $cars->plate; ?></td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="bericht[]" value="<?php echo $cars->message; ?>"><?php echo $cars->message; ?></td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="fahrer[]" value="<?php echo $cars->driver; ?>"><?php echo $cars->driver; ?></td>
    </tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>

       </tbody>
    </table> 
    <input type="submit" name="senden" value="XML speichern" />
</form>
```

and with this i write it into the database:

```
 <?php

     error_reporting(E_ALL); 
        $MYSQL_HOST = 'localhost'; 
        $MYSQL_USER = 'username'; 
        $MYSQL_PASS = 'password'; 
        $MYSQL_DATA = 'database'; 

        $connid = @mysql_connect($MYSQL_HOST, $MYSQL_USER, $MYSQL_PASS) OR die("Error: ".mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db($MYSQL_DATA) OR die("Error: ".mysql_error()); 

       if (isset($_POST['senden']))
    {
     $count = count($_POST['name']);
      for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
      $sql = 
              "INSERT INTO myTable 
              (fahrzeug,
               kennzeichen,
               bericht,
               fahrer
              )
              VALUES
              ('".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['name']))."',
               '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['kfz-nr']))."', 
               '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['bericht']))."',  
               '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['fahrer']))."'); 
                mysql_query($sql) OR die("<pre>\n".$sql."</pre>\n".mysql_error()); 
                mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    }
 }
echo "Daten eingetragen";
?>
```

I also tried already to remove some specialchars etc. like:

```
<td><input type="hidden" name="bericht[]" value="<?php echo str_replace(["\n", "\r", "\r\n", "\n\n", "\x20-\x7f", "\0", "\t", "\x0B"], '', $cars->message) ; ?>"><?php echo str_replace(["\n", "\r", "\r\n", "\n\n", "\x20-\x7f", "\0", "\t", "\x0B"], '', $cars->message); ?></td>
```

but i still get not the right 'bericht' to the row where it belong. :(

Here a short part from the XML. I hope it's enough. I don't know where it is going wrong, but the whole XML is about 30 MB. As i said. Almost every 'bericht' will be written in the wrong row. In this case may be the 'bericht' from Heiko H. will be written in the row of Frank P.

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <car>
      <cars>
        <typ>personal</typ>
        <plate>4528-58</plate>
        <message>gestern wurde genau 2mal etwas entnommen.</message>
        <driver>Heiko H.</driver>
      </cars>
      <cars>
        <typ>personal</typ>
        <plate>4528-59</plate>
        <message>Die Fahrt war kurz. einige Sachen wurdne mitgebracht!

    Inhalt:
    2 Flaschen Öl
    Schraubendreher
    Etui aus Metall mit Schlüssel

    Tasche aus Polyester, Polyurethan und nickelfreiem Metall.</message>
          <driver>Frank P.</driver>
      </cars>
    </car>
```

Comment: Can we see a snippet of the XML file for reproducible example?

Comment: I edited my psot and added a bit from the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your `for` loop does not index the `$_POST` variable arrays with the `$i` iterator. Each variable should be number indexed to align properly with same XML siblings/database rows:

```
...
$sql = "INSERT INTO myTable (fahrzeug, kennzeichen, bericht, fahrer )
        VALUES
        ('".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['name'][$i]))."',
         '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['kfz-nr'][$i]))."', 
         '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['bericht'][$i]))."',  
         '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['fahrer'][$i]))."')"; 
...
```

Additionally, do not use the obsolete `mysql_*` functions which has been declared [deprecated in PHP 5.5](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation) and ultimiately [removed in PHP 7](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7#extmysql). Use `mysqli`, `PDO`, or other current database API. Finally, use parameterized queries especially if data derives from the web (which avoids wrapping values in quotes). Below is an example re-work of your script with `mysqli`, binded parameterization, and `try/catch` exception handling. Notice also anticipating empty XML elements with `if/else`:

```
try {
    // OPEN DB CONNECTION
    $connid = new mysqli($MYSQL_HOST, $MYSQL_USER, $MYSQL_PASS, $MYSQL_DATA);
    $connid->set_charset("utf8");
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);

    // PREPARE STATEMENT
    $sql = "INSERT INTO myTable (fahrzeug, kennzeichen, bericht, fahrer)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = $connid->prepare($sql);

    if (isset($_POST['senden'])){        
        $count = count($_POST['name']);

        for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){        

           // CONDITIONALLY HANDLE POST ARRAY ELEMENTS
           if(!empty($_POST['name'][$i])) { $name = 
                     mysqli_real_escape_string($connid, trim($_POST['name'][$i])); }
              else { $name = null; }
           if(!empty($_POST['kfz-nr'][$i])) { $kfznr = 
                     mysqli_real_escape_string($connid, trim($_POST['kfz-nr'][$i])); }
              else { $kfznr = null; }
           if(!empty($_POST['bericht'][$i])) { $bericht = 
                     mysqli_real_escape_string($connid, trim($_POST['bericht'][$i])); }
              else { $bericht = null; }
           if(!empty($_POST['fahrer'][$i])) { $fahrer = 
                     mysqli_real_escape_string($connid, trim($_POST['fahrer'][$i])); }
              else { $fahrer = null; }

           // BIND PARAMETERS                
           $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $name, $kfznr, $bericht, $fahrer);

           // EXECUTE QUERY
           $stmt->execute();
      }
    }
} catch(Exception $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

# CLOSE DB CONNECTION
$connid->close();
$connid = null;
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried your code but now i get always a _Column 'fahrzeug' cannot be null_ . If i remove that completely and try to insert just the other 3 values than i get _Column 'kennzeichen' cannot be null_ . and so on
but there is no single entry written to my database.

Comment: Hmmm...which code version? Your old mysql or the mysqli re-write? Also, reason for messages is you have those fields set to *not null* in MySQL. But it seems indexing `[$i]` is not working if null is trying to be inserted. Try echoing in the loop: `echo ".$_POST['name'][$i]."  ".$_POST['kfz-nr'][$i]. " ".$_POST['bericht'][$i]." ".$_POST['fahrer'][$i];`..does it return values?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer.
I get the values only of the first row and at the end _Column 'fahrzeug' cannot be null_
in PHPmyAdmin all columns are marked with 'NULL - NO' But if i set it to yes i get only NULL instead of any data.

Comment: Just found the issue! It came down to `mysqli_real_escape_string()` which was stripping out the value as the function requires the connection object as first parameter. See edited post and try again.

Comment: Thanks. Now i get the values into my databse but i still get _Column 'bericht' cannot be null_

Comment: I found that some elements <message></message> in the XML are empty so i replaced them with <message>++0++</message>, but it seems that there also some other elements are empty or completely missed. Could that the reason why 'bericht' isn't in the right row? And if so, can i do anything to prevent it?

Comment: I cannot recreate your issue. Code accounts for missing elements: `if(!empty($_POST[...][$i])`. Check the structure of your XML. Is there other nesting other than posted example? It is interesting `<car>` is parent to `<cars>`.

Comment: Hi,
is there a chance to contact you privat via mail or something like this? There i can better explain the whole thing. :)
I tried to move this to a chat but i havn't enogh reputation yet. And i can't find any way to send a private message at stackoverflow.

Comment: i guess i found the problem. It seems that there are some characters in 'bericht' that not be valid. But i don't know where and what chars it is.
I try to remove them with notpad++